# grep multiple regex of a line

Tags: regex, filter, grep, field, syslog

I want to log incoming syslog from my router to a file. I recieve the syslog with

```
nc -l -u -p 514 > syslog.log
```

The incoming lines are made of several fields that are separated by a whitespace.

Here are two complete sample lines from syslog:

```
<4>Nov 29 16:15:29 kernel: [ 3571.330000] DROP IN=vlan2 OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00 SRC=1.235.114.117 DST=1.52.79.209 LEN=337 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=115 ID=30831 PROTO=UDP SPT=161 DPT=220 LEN=317
<4>Nov 29 16:15:30 kernel: [ 3572.200000] DROP IN=vlan2 OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00 SRC=7.27.203.227 DST=122.2.79.209 LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=52 ID=44018 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=5108 DPT=220 SEQ=3468909622 ACK=0 WIND
```

I want only the Time,SRC,PROTO,SPT,DPT fields in my logifile so I thought I could use something like this as a test for DST and SRC only:

```
nc -l -u -p 514 | egrep -o 'SRC=[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}|DST=[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}' > syslog.log
```

Unfortatly this prints every field in a new line like this:

```
SRC=1.235.114.117
DST=1.52.79.209
SRC=7.27.203.227
DST=122.2.79.209
```

I then want a output looking simmilar to this corresponding to the first line:
Time,SRC,PROTO,SPT,DPT

```
Nov 29 16:15:29,7.27.203.227,TCP,5108,220
```

There is another problem. Sometimes I receive lines that does not contain a "DS" field like in the second line of the samples. So counting fields with awk separators seems not to work since they are not consistent.

Anyone an idea how I can do this?

Comment: I suggest to switch from `grep` to `sed`.

Comment: Why are you even using `nc` for remote syslog functionality? Install `rsyslog` or `syslog-ng` or one of the other options. Some of them even have filters/hooks that you can put in place to handle what you want to do...

Comment: I just did a quick look at syslog-ng, but I cant find any options to reformat the lines output field. Of cause I can filter lines of different content to different destination log files, but I cannot see how to reorder the fields in the line itself. Did I miss something in syslog-ng?

Comment: @PaulG. The official documentation [here](https://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/index.html) has an entire chapter (11) on modifying messages. In addition, messages can be logged to named pipes or as input to custom programs, so you can accomplish pretty much anything you need to.

Answer (score 0):

As @twalberg suggested I now use syslog-ng.

this is my syslog-ng.conf:

```
@version: 3.7
@include "scl.conf"
options {
    threaded(yes);
    chain_hostnames(no);
    stats_freq(43200);
    mark_freq(3600);
};
source s_udp { udp(port(514)); };
parser p_kv {kv-parser(prefix(".kv.")); };
destination d_router_file { file("/var/log/firewall_drops.csv" template("${DATE},${.kv.SRC}${.kv.PROTO},${.kv.SPT},${.kv.DPT}\n")); };
log { source(s_udp);parser(p_kv);destination(d_router_file); };
```